# contrast to find dependence on continuous variable within a group?

Tags: r, linear-model

I have a linear model like `Y ~ group * X`, where `X` is a continuous variable and `group` is a categorical variable. Let's say `group` designates different animals (badgers, ferrets, or weasels), `X` is bees per hectare, and `Y` is, umm, average tail size. Now I know how to ask, what is the dependence of ferret tail length on bee density, but how do I determine if that dependence statistically significant?

```
set.seed(1)
mustelid <- c("badger", "ferret", "weasel")
dat <- data.frame(tail=rnorm(100, 10, 1),
                  mustelid=sample(mustelid, 100, replace=T),
                  bees=rnorm(100, 1000, 100))
## add dependence of tail length on bees but only for non-ferrets
dat$tail <- dat$tail + ifelse(dat$mustelid=="ferret", 0, 10 - dat$bees / 100)
lmObj <- lm(tail ~ mustelid * bees, data=dat)
```

and the summary is:

```
Call:
lm(formula = tail ~ mustelid * bees, data = dat)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.06766 -0.54566  0.02774  0.55211  2.34569 

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         19.035790   1.248556  15.246  < 2e-16 ***
mustelidferret      -8.123115   1.995913  -4.070 9.79e-05 ***
mustelidweasel       6.065957   2.172758   2.792 0.006349 ** 
bees                -0.008956   0.001232  -7.269 1.06e-10 ***
mustelidferret:bees  0.008085   0.001996   4.051 0.000105 ***
mustelidweasel:bees -0.005865   0.002138  -2.743 0.007293 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.8798 on 94 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5712,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5484 
F-statistic: 25.05 on 5 and 94 DF,  p-value: 5.762e-16
```

So the estimated dependence of ferret tail length on bee density is (iinm), the `bees` coefficient plus the `mustelidferret:bees` coefficient. Both of these coefficients are significant by themselves, but I can't tell how I'd figure out if their sum is significant. Any suggestion?

For reference, here's a plot showing how tail length changes with bee density (bees per hectare, by the way, is definitely, absolutely, beyond all question an important factor in [mustelid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustelidae) ecology):

[image: tail length vs. bee density]

Basically, we expect our model to show that tail length varies with bee density in weasels and badgers but not ferrets.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this using the `glht` function from the `multcomp` package. `glht(lmObj, linfct)` will query `lmObj` with the contrast named by the `linfct` argument (typically called a *contrast vector* although `glht` expects its argument to be a `matrix`). As noted in the question, the effect we're trying to test is the sum of the `bees` and `mustelidferret:bees` coefficients. Such a contrast vector would have ones associated with those coefficients and zeros associated with the rest.

```
names(coef(lmObj))
## [1] "(Intercept)"         "mustelidferret"      "mustelidweasel"     
## [4] "bees"                "mustelidferret:bees" "mustelidweasel:bees"
```

so we want the fourth and fifth coefficients:

```
library(multcomp)
summary(glht(lmObj, linfct=matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,0), nrow=1)))
```

which gives,

```
     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Fit: lm(formula = tail ~ mustelid * bees, data = dat)

Linear Hypotheses:
         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
1 == 0 -0.0008711  0.0015703  -0.555     0.58
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Not significant, as expected.